# Why "import tensorflow.python.something" instead of "import tensorflow.something"?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I noticed that quite a few examples for tensorflow (and answers, [here is a random one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45772865/2421916)) include the statement

```
import tensorflow.python.something
```

while others use

```
import tensorflow.something
```

Looking through the [Tensorflow API Reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf), I could not find the module `python`. What could be the reason to use the `tensorflow.python` syntax, and why is it working even though it appears to be undocumented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the source code of [tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/__init__.py)

> These symbols appear because we import the python package which in
>   turn imports from tensorflow.core and tensorflow.python. They must
>   come from this module. So python adds these symbols for the resolution
>   to succeed.

From the technical perspective it's valid but an unsafe way to import since it's not documented and it tends to change.